# Exchange 2010 Log Generation

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010, logging, transaction-log

We have an Exchange server which is generating roughly 7GB of Transaction logs per day, for a 75GB Database, does this sound normal? I'm fairly new to Exchange and am looking for some stats and averages really from other admins.

The database has roughly 25 mailboxes, so it's no big shakes

Thanks!

Comment: Why would it not be normal?  Logs are based on change rates of mailbox data, which is unique to the people and business.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The transaction logs will grow based upon the number of Transactions (funny how that works).  So if your environment is generating transactions at a rate that produces 7GB of logs a day, then it's normal.  Ultimately, you need to determine if this is normal behavior or not.

However, if you are new to exchange, please setup an exchange aware backup of your databases and make sure your committed logs get flushed (deleted).  Otherwise your log partition will fill and exchange will bring the databases offline until there is available storage.